# Why do some object emit full visible spectrum of light while some only emit specific frequency?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, spectroscopy

We get a full visible spectrum of light emission from a filament inside lightbulb but only certain frequencies for individual atoms. Since this filament is also made up of combinations of atoms, shouldn't it also give out specific frequencies?

Answer (score 2):

*. . . . . but only certain frequencies for **individual** atom?*
Your question points in the right direction because once atoms are interacting with their neighbors the energy levels are broadened and so many more transitions are possible leading to a (nearly) continuous spectrum.

Comment: In a hydrogen gas discharge tube, bunch of hydrogen atom interact with each other and still emits only certain frequencies in visible spectrum of light, not a continuous spectrum. How come when (let's say) a filament made of Tungsten emits continuous spectrum when it's just tungsten interacting with each other?

Comment: In the Hydrogen tube there is some broadening of the spectral lines due to interactions between the atoms/molecules but the interactions between the atoms in solid are much, much stronger, thus the emission spectrum becomes (almost) continuous.

Comment: Okay, but if a single atom (call 'A') can emit (say frequency 1,2,3), then even with 100 atoms of 'A', shouldn't it still only emit frequency 1,2,3? Meaning it wouldn't really broaden the emission spectrum but since it has more atom, more probability of emitting those frequencies, it would have more intense lines of emission spectrum. Please correct me if this is not the case...

Comment: No, because each of the quantum jumps from well defined level $A$ to well defined level $B$ which produces a line spectrum now, with interactions between the atoms, become jumps from a continuum of level (band) which was well defined level $A$ to a continuum of level (band) which was well defined level $B$ and so there are now many more wavelength emitted where there was just one.

Comment: I'm sorry... I couldn't understand what you wrote. Are there key words for this phenomena that I could do more googling on? Thank you for your effort.